# Linear Transformation Concept Question

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Consider that we have a given standard matrix of T and we are asked to find the image T(X) where X is a given vector. T is 4x3 and X is 3x1. is the solution of T(x) simply T*X?

Comment: Omid: You've asked a handful of questions and received many answers. We encourage users who post a question and receive answers they find to be helpful to accept an answer. You can accept only one answer per question, and to accept an answer, you simply click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. Soon you'll be able to upvote answers, too, and when you can (just a little more reputation), then you can upvote as many answers as you'd like! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If a basis is fixed, and you express $T$ and $x$ as matrices in terms of that basis, then $T(x)=T*x$ with matrix multiplication.

If you change bases, then the matrices in which $T$ and $x$ are expressed are probably going to change, but the result will still be computed with matrix multiplication, and it will yield the same result as $T(x)$.